# product catalog api fail

Tags: facebook, api, product, dpi

need help.
I tried to start with `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/dynamic-product-ads/ads-management/v2.3`
created account. Approved it by `phone`.
created a business account, an ad account, an app, and so on.
linked app to ad accont like this `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/access#standard_accounts`. 
Now i tried to create product catalog. i am getting same error all the time:

```
 The app is not whitelisted to use this API
```

i tried to call api to cteate/list/managment product catalog.
when i did, the same by UI - i can create product catalog & feed.
but by API - all time error.
i do not understand what it need?

now try to create product set:

```
GET /<product_catalog ID>/product_sets/?
access_token=<my access token from app with full rights get from exploer>
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) The app is not whitelisted to use this API",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200
  }
}
```

try to create the same:

```
POST : /v2.3/<product_catalog ID>/product_sets/?access_token=<my access token from app with full rights get from exploer>&name=my new prod set
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#275) Ad account cannot be determined for this request",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 275
  }
}
```

So what Are the changes i needed to make it work?

is it any way to made api calls work correctly?

p.s. 
  i guess something wrong in settings - i run unit tests in SDK - have the same situation. i have read about that problems with game app - but my app - is not a game, so i cant use solution in my situation. 
  if some body understand what whitelist API want  - please help!
Thanks.

Comment: upd: try to create in business manager project. add there my AD account, my page, and try to add catalog. when i try to add a catalog i have a message "(#10) Application does not have permission for this action " its strange, becose i do not use any application - only facebook. may be problem in other place

Comment: upd: strange. deleta all app, ad company , catalogs. left business account only. recreate catalog - it has no errors.

Comment: also getting this error, despite following instructions at this link under "managing account list" section: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/access#standard_accounts. Unfortunately, deleting a bunch of stuff and recreating it is not an option.

Comment: Hi Pavan, Were you able to get this to work ? Stuck in a similar situation, any pointers would be very helpful;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is explained by the documentation you linked to - unless your app is approved for `Standard` access to the API it can only access a specific number of ad accounts and those accounts need to be pre-configured in the app settings

Many of the business manager APIs can't be used because they're not tied to one of those pre-specified accounts (hence the `Ad account cannot be determined for this request` error).

In general, the business manager APIs likely won't work for you until your app has access at the `standard` level, though some will if they're account-specific

Comment: Thanks! If I undersnand your message correctly:   There are NO way to test DPI API - untill i do not have worked api used app. & I can not have access , until i do not have worked (and tested) app. So it is NO way to write app, that use DPI. am i understand correct?

Comment: DPi = DPA https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/dynamic-product-ads/ads-management/v2.3

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully this helps someone else: I was also trying to create a Product Catalog via the API in Development, and got "The app is not whitelisted to use this API".

I solved it by creating an **admin** system user, and generating an access token with the `business_management` permission.

Comment: I tried the same, but it still answers 'Not whitelisted'

Answer (score 0):

You can't be an app admin and a tester/developer at the same time. You should create another facebook account for tests.

Answer (score 0):

This happens also when the access token used is not from your app which has Standard Access. Also, note the dev version of the same app will not work.