# (#200) The app is not whitelisted to use this API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to access the facebook API to retrieve all the catalogs of a particular business, I know this has already been answered over [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29693496/product-catalog-api-fail](http://Product%20API) but the answer suggests that you need to have standard level access on your which I do, I figured that I might have to use the **marketing** product in facebook app, but that was of no help too,

If any one has any ideas on how to solve it?

Thanks

Error Image

[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to get the permission for "Business Asset User Profile Access" ..
you can get that from Permissions and Features
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7edY.png)

Comment: The Standart permission is already activated. The advanced permissions requires App review, but such app review is not possible until the Test application works with that permissions. But using TestApp has the same error as in the question. Catch 22

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution regarding that error,
Just go to your Facebook account menu top right, select parameter, parameter and authorization, on the left side of page, scroll down, select professional integration and in the list renew the broken's authorizations
Hope it's gonna works for you.